# searching commit messages in the whole git repo

Tags: git, grep, git-log

I'd like to understand the difference between `git log --all --grep=<>` and `git log --grep=<>`. My goal is to traverse the whole repo when searching. If I don't add `--all`, does it mean that I will miss all the commit messages in branches? Looks like a non-intuitive default to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you need `--all` here (or perhaps you might want `--branches` instead).

"Intuitive" in git is a bit tricky, and the behavior of `git log` *is* intuitive to me, but only because I've studied git and its peculiar notions of how to work with commit graphs.

The `log` command is not very different from all the other commit-graph-traversing commands.  They all work like—in fact, many of then simply run, or run and then use the output of—`git rev-list`.  You give it some starting point commit IDs, or some names or any of the syntax described in [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), and it finds the SHA-1 IDs of every commit reachable from those IDs.

*Every* commit inside the repo—including commits that have been "abandoned" (but are still findable via reflogs) because of a rebase copy operation, commits that are on the stash stack, and even `git notes` commits—works this way, so it would be bad for `git log` to find all commits.  Even the `--all` flag doesn't actually find all commits.

If you peruse [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), you'll see that `--all` means "every reference in the `refs/` namespace" (hence all branches, all tags, and notes, but not special references like `ORIG_HEAD` left behind after a rebase, nor any reflog entries, for instance).  The same wording appears in [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), but I like to refer people to `git rev-list` since I think it is ultimately more revealing.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it excludes merged branches? Could you be more specific about which nodes are "reachable" according to git from a certain commit?

Comment: "Reachability" is a graph-theoritic term, but the idea is simple enough: given a starting commit (default being `HEAD`), the graph-walker visits that commit, then its parent commit, then that commit's parent, and so on.  A merge commit is simply a commit with two (or more) parents, at which point the graph walker has to visit both (and all their parents).  See http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/reachability.html and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156501 for instance; in the latter, c589395 is a merge, so the walker must visit both 9f9c652 and b3bd158.

Answer (score 1):

`git log` is a tool for traversing the commit graph and printing out commit information. `--grep` is a *filter* on this traverse.

---

`git log` starts from your current commit (ie. `HEAD`) and works its way back through history from there.

`git log --all` visits all commits.  This is pretty rare, occasionally needed by an integrator.

`--grep` is a filter.  It filters the stream of commits visited by `git log`.  Filters only *remove* entries, never add.  For each commit `git log` visits `--grep` decides whether that should be included.  It might make more sense if you think of it like a normal Unix pipe.

```
git log | grep foo
```

---

Defaults should work best with the most common case.  Commands like `diff` and `log` are most used in *development*.  Integration happens far more rarely.  So the defaults are targeted at developers.

The common use of `git log` for developers is looking for changes which contributed to this commit. They're looking for answers to the question "why is this written like this?" or "where did this bug come from?".  That's why the default is to walk the graph from your current commit.  It's rare that you want to search commits which haven't been merged into your code, that's more the task of an integration manager.

`--grep` doesn't change what commits `git log` visits.  If it implied `--all`, that would be surprising and inflexible.  Surprising because it would muddle the meaning of "filter" and it's pretty rare you want to search unrelated branches.  Inflexible because how do you search only certain commits?  I suppose you could require a `--no-all` to turn it off, and then maybe more switches, probably `--branches`, to get what you mean.

There are rare instances where having multiple default behaviors works out, but it's usually a nightmare.  It's better to have a firm common use case in mind (development) and not guess about rarer cases (integration).  Let rare cases be explicit about what they want.